# How to efficiently delete an element from a slice in Go?

Tags: go, memory-management, slice

There are several approaches to deleting slice element(-s). But  what if I have an application that intensively working with slices. Go slices are optimised very well for adding new elements, but is there an efficient way to delete element(-s) from slice (not only speed, but also memory optimised).

I know about [slices.Delete](https://pkg.go.dev/slices@master#Delete) function that was introduced in Go 1.21, but under the hood it uses the following well-known technique:

```
return append(s[:i], s[j:]...)
```

Looks like the underlying array will not be decreased in such a case. This is good for speed, but what if we had a lot of elements (for example, 100k or 1M) and then reduced them to a very few (e.g., only 10). Looks like there are no memory optimisation like the one that is used for increasing slice capacity.

When we don't need to preserve the order of the elements in a slice the following approach can be used ([go playground link](https://stackoverflow.com)):

```
func sliceDel[S ~[]E, E any](s S, i, j int) S {
    lastIdx := len(s) - (j - i)
    copy(s[i:], s[lastIdx:])
    return s[:lastIdx]
}
```

This can be useful when we have big slice and a small number of elements to delete (the idea behind it is to copy a small number of slice elements).

Regarding memory, in both cases capacity will be the same and it will not be reduced. For example:

```
    // Reduce slice almost to zero
    for i := 0; i < sliceSize/2-1; i++ {
        sl = sliceDel(sl, 0, 2)
    }
    fmt.Printf("len = %d, cap = %d", len(sl), cap(sl))
        // Output: len = 2, cap = 100000

    // Reduce slice almost to zero
    for i := 0; i < sliceSize/2-1; i++ {
        sl = slices.Delete(sl, 0, 2)
    }
    fmt.Printf("len = %d, cap = %d", len(sl), cap(sl))
        // Output: len = 2, cap = 100000
```

So, is there a way to optimize memory usage? For example, if the length of a slice is less than a half of its capacity, reduce the capacity by half.

I am also wondering how to do it efficiently, for example such a technique `s[:len(s):len(s)]` ([full slice expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) is used by [slices.Clip](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/exp/+/d852ddb8:slices/slices.go;l=403)) will not decrease underlaying array - it only saves new capacity in a slice struct to avoid rewriting parent slice elements in case of appending new elements to a sub-slice (as it is mentioned in [this proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GKKdiGYAghXRxC2BFrSEbHBZZgAGKQ-yXK-hRKBo0Kk/pub)).

Comment: If you want to ensure that you use a smaller array allocation, then you need to copy the elements into a smaller array. It's theoretically possible that a full slice expression could release part of the allocation at some point: see https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/SNY2ZCiNV-U/m/oL2feeUlDAAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "general best" solution. You showed multiple ways in your question, each being potentially better than the others for specific scenarios.

> This is good for speed, but what if we had a lot of elements (for example, 100k or 1M) and then reduced it to a very few (e.g., only 10).

If you have such a case when you want to retain few elements out of many, don't even start deleting those. Build a new slice with those few elements. This for sure solves the memory issue, too, besides being much faster.

Other than allocating and using a new slice, you can't reduce the memory usage by using a full slice expression. As long as there's a reference to the backing array, it won't shrink (not with the current Go version at least). If you're in a situation where a big backing array is allocated but you're only using a small portion of it, you may allocate a new slice and copy the elements manually to let the big one get garbage collected.

Also consider that if you have a big slice from which you may have to remove many elements, a slice may not be the best data structure. You may experiment with a linked list for example, or you may even try a map: removing an element from a linked list or map will be much-much faster, the map will also provide fast (`O(n)`) lookup time as well.

Comment: Thank you. I think alternative data structures such as you proposed (hash maps, linked lists) will be better solution. I was just wondering is there any options when for slices, may be I missed something.

Answer (score -2):

If, as you say (and I have no reason to doubt it), slices are well suited to use cases where items are being appended but not efficient when removing items, and you have a use case where you need to perform lots of efficient removals from large collections of items, then you should perhaps consider using something other than a slice.

[container/list](https://pkg.go.dev/container/list) could be a candidate.